# Inner Join - retornar pelo id nome em coluna de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho duas tabelas no DB:

tabela **categoria**:

```
id_categoria | nome_categoria
   1             camisetas
   2             estrelas
```

tabela **post**:

```
id_post | título | resumo | conteúdo | categoria_id
    1      teste    lorem     ipsum         2
    2      test2    lorem     ipsum         1
```

Se eu acessar na url: `www.exemplo.com/camisetas`

`camisetas` é a variavel `$categoria` por causa da regra no .htaccess

Eu quero acessar todos os dados da coluna `categoria_id` da tabela `posts` por nome e não por id:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post where ".$categoria." ";
```

qual instrução inner join uso nesse caso? Ou melhor como eu adiciono o inner join nesse select?

Agradeço ajuda

---

**ATUALIZANDO**

Para o select estou fazendo assim:

```
public function dataview($query)
    {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM post 
              JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_categoria = post.categoria_id 
              WHERE categoria.nome_categoria = '".$categoria."'"; 


        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                echo // aqui as linhas que quero
            }
        }
        else
        {
                echo // aqui o que for necessario
        }

    }
```

Para o insert assim:

```
public function add($titulo, $etc)
{
try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO post (o_titulo, o_etc)
                                           VALUES(:o_titulo, :o_etc)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":o_titulo",$titulo);
        $stmt->bindParam(":o_etc",$etc);  
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();    
        return false;
    }
```

No htaccess também determinei a quantidade de caracteres e tipo, quanto ao tipo a maioria somente letras (sem números e caracteres), dentro de cada parte da url `/`

Esta vuraneável desta forma?

Comment: Para complementar, em seu metodo dataview eu colocaria a query dessa forma:
`SELECT * FROM post 
              JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_categoria = post.categoria_id 
              WHERE categoria.nome_categoria = ?`

E adicionaria `$stmt->bindParam(1,$categoria);` antes do `$stmt->execute();`, no mais parece estar ok.

Comment: Obrigada Antonio tudo funcionando. O `bindParam` (como consta no manual) e `bindparam` são coisas diferentes? Com p minusculo não aparecia erros para mim, das duas formas não aparecem erros, mas em um post li que bindparam com letras minusculas faz com que o `bindParam` não execute. Não sei se isso é verdadeiro

Comment: Nome das funções no PHP não são case-sensitivos, isso significa que se você chamar bindParam ou bindparam é a mesma coisa, estará acessando a função normalmente. :)

Comment: Muito obrigada @AntonioJr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o que você procura seria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM post 
       JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_categoria = post.categoria_id 
WHERE id_post = 'id_do seu post'
```

Veja bem, eu seu exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post where ".$categoria." ";
```

Você deixa a entender que `$categoria` executa a condicional do sua query, isso é extremamente vulnereavel a ataques sql injection.

Recomendo dar uma pesquisada sobre e como melhorar isso.

De qualquer forma a query que eu lhe apresentei faz o JOIN da tabela `post` com a `categoria`, pelo `id_categoria da categoria` com `categoria_id da post`, basta trocar o condicional da clasula WHERE de sua query para a condição de pesquisa desejada na tabela post.

Comment: Obrigada Antonio, mas para retornar somente os nomes, camiseta, estrela, etc, o where não deveria ser o nome_categoria?

Comment: Sim, você pode fazer `WHERE categoria.nome_catogoria = '".$categoria."';` mas continuo alertando, muito cuidado com SQL Injection, essa query esta altamente vulnerável, recomendo utilizar PDO utilizando prepare e bindParam, esse link pode te ajudar: http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973

Comment: Obrigada @AntonioJr, é um ótimo artigo, aprendi mais algumas coisas que antes eram dificeis de entender. Adicionei informações na minha pergunta, por favor veja se esta vulnerável